# "His voice cracked with the strain"

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference

> His voice **cracked with the strain**, and they stood looking at each other in the whiteness and the emptiness, and Harry felt they were as insignificant as insects beneath that wide sky.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

I only found "[crack under the strain](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cracking+under+the+strain)". Is there any difference between "crack under the strain" and "crack with the strain"?

Comment: It is an error. Try searching for the exact test using quote marks "His voice cracked with the strain, and they stood looking at each other in the whiteness and the emptiness" and you will see that the word is **'strain'**. Whatever source you are using is suspect.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Cracked *under* the strain" would refer to something *physically* breaking under *literal* strain. For example, if a wooden shelf cracked into two pieces because a heavy weight had been placed on it.

A voice "cracking" is not so literal - when vocal cords are strained, the audible breaks in a person's voice are referred to as "cracks". The thing that is being strained is not the same thing that "breaks" in this example, so it doesn't seem right to say that the voice cracked *under* the strain - it cracked *with* the strain.

Also worthy of note is that "cracked under the *pressure*" is a common idiom, but "pressure" can refer to both emotional pressure as well as physical pressure, and the results.

Comment: So, if I am just a guy passing by, I will think this answer is wrong because it has a (-1). Why is this wrong then?